# How to check whether a key exist inside a nested dictionary and if yes delete

Tags: python

I have this `main_dict` created and want to see if `main_dict[x]["Description"]` exists or not, and if yes, then delete it. Where `x` is `'pins'`, `'nails'`, `'board'`, etc ...

```
main_dict = {
'pins':
    {
        'Category': ['General'],
        'Contact': ['Mark'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
    },
'nails':
    {
        'Category': ['specific'],
        'Contact': ['Jon'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
    },
'board':
    {
        'Category': ['General'],
        'Contact': ['Mark'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
    },
'hammer':
    {
        'Category': ['tools'],
        'Contact': ['Jon'],
        'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
for x in main_dict:
   del main_dict[x]["Description"]
```

This returns error if `main_dict[x]["Description"]` does not exist.

Also this does not work:

```
if main_dict[x]["Description"] in mainDict[x]:
     del main_dict[x]["Description"]
```

Comment: The second works if you use it correctly. Try: `if "Description" in main_dict[x] `

Comment: that works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would remove it from any sub-dictionaries that contain it:

```
main_dict = {
    'pins':
        {
            'Category': ['General'],
            'Contact': ['Mark'],
            'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
        },
    'nails':
        {
            'Category': ['specific'],
            'Contact': ['Jon'],
            'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
        },
    'board':
        {
            'Category': ['General'],
            'Contact': ['Mark'],
            'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
        },
    'hammer':
        {
            'Category': ['tools'],
            'Contact': ['Jon'],
            'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
        }
}

for key, value in main_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict) and 'Description' in value:
        del value['Description']
```

Result:

```
{
    'pins':
        {
            'Category': ['General'],
            'Contact': ['Mark'],
        },
    'nails':
        {
            'Category': ['specific'],
            'Contact': ['Jon'],
        },
    'board':
        {
            'Category': ['General'],
            'Contact': ['Mark'],
        },
    'hammer':
        {
            'Category': ['tools'],
            'Contact': ['Jon'],
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply use `pop()` method with default argument(e.g. `None`) to omit checking if `"Description"` exist as key.

```
for i in main_dict:
    main_dict[i].pop("Description", None)
```

*Note:* it's not a good practice to change iterable object while iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:

```
for x in main_dict:
    if "Description" in main_dict[x]:
        main_dict[x].pop("Description")
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a key is in a dictionary try `if key in dict` to check in nested dictionaries you follow the same logic:

```
for key in main_dict:
    if 'Description' in main_dict[key]:
        # do something
```

About removing an element, you should indeed use the [`del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del_stmt). I copied your main_dict, and ran the same as you:

```
for x in main_dict: 
    del main_dict[x]['Description']
```

Maybe you're trying to remove it twice?